# if else condition for multiple installs

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create a blueprint out of this shell script to install different rpms on different systems and matching the system type. In this example, I have total 2 systems named centos1 and suse1. Each system have a corresponding resource id stored in variable "id" and should run commands matching each. All the system names are read from the text file named vm.txt.

```
~]# cat vm.txt
centos1
suse1

~]# ./myscript.sh vm.txt

        #!/bin/bash
        for node in `cat $1`
        do
          # id is the resource id for each system listed in vm.txt
          id=`./test.sh get resource id --platform=$node`
          if [ $node == centos1 ]
          then
            echo `./install.sh resource $id centos1-httpd`
            echo `./install.sh resource $id centos1-gcc`
          elif [ $node == suse1 ]
          then
            echo `./install.sh resource $id suse1-httpd`
            echo `./install.sh resource $id suse1-gcc`
          else 
            echo "No packages found"
          fi
        done
```

Going forward I will have to add several hundreds of systems into the script file and the install criterias. I am not sure using if-else condition in this script which would end up in writing more lines of code causing difficulties to manage later.. Is there a better way to handle this? Should I use a different condition than if-else to accomplish this?

PS: sorry for this basic question. I am still trying to get my hands-on into scripting.

Comment: `for node in \`cat $1\``: don't do this. [Please refer to this link for more information](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Also, go and complain to the guy or site who gave you that horrible information. Do it. Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
   #!/bin/bash
    while read -d $'\n' -r node;
    do
      # id is the resource id for each system listed in vm.txt
      id=`./test.sh get resource id --platform=$node`
      echo `./install.sh resource $id ${node}-httpd`
      echo `./install.sh resource $id ${node}-gcc`
    done < "$1"
```

To please @choroba

```
   #!/bin/bash
    known_nodes=" centos1 suse1 " # leading and final space are important

    while read -d $'\n' -r node
    do
      if [[ " $node " =~ "$known_nodes" ]]; then
        # id is the resource id for each system listed in vm.txt
        id=`./test.sh get resource id --platform=$node`

        echo `./install.sh resource $id ${node}-httpd`
        echo `./install.sh resource $id ${node}-gcc`
      else
        echo "Don't know node ${node}. Skipping."
      fi
    done < "$1"
```

Comment: I would add a verification that the $node has a valid value.

Comment: `for node in \`cat $1\``. Please don't do this. See my comment to Tiago's answer.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf yeah you are right but it was so tempting. His file is just perfectly formatted for it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` will be easier to add distros as you go along than `elseif`:

```
tiago@dell:/tmp$ cat myscript.sh 
#! /bin/bash

for node in $(cat $1); do
    id=$(./test.sh get resource id --platform=$node)
    case $node in
        centos1)
            echo "./install.sh resource $id centos1-httpd"
            echo "./install.sh resource $id centos1-gcc"    
        ;;

        suse1)
            echo "./install.sh resource $id suse1-httpd"
            echo "./install.sh resource $id suse1-gcc"
        ;;    

        *)
            echo "No Packages found"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Execution:

```
tiago@dell:/tmp$ bash myscript.sh  <(echo -e 'centos1\nsuse1\nfedora')
./install.sh resource  centos1-httpd
./install.sh resource  centos1-gcc
./install.sh resource  suse1-httpd
./install.sh resource  suse1-gcc
No Packages found
```

Comment: Thanks Tiago. I also have a resource id mapped against each node, which is stored in variable "id". This id need to be identified and added to install.sh command. where should I specify that in this script?  id=`./test.sh get resource id --platform=$node`

Comment: I put it in the right place. Mind you that `echo "./install.sh resource $id suse1-httpd"` should be `echo $(./install.sh resource $id suse1-httpd)`. I put it between quotes so I could print instead of execute.

Comment: `for node in $(cat $1); do`. Please don't use this! As an exercise, try to imagine some cases where this fails miserably and why it is terribly broken and why the world would be much better if such horrible, wrong and broken information was not so widely available on the web. And we want SO to be a _quality_ site, so please, please! don't post garbage on SO. Use another site for this.

Comment: hey @gniourf_gniourf I am here to learn more than anything else.  `while IFS= read -r node; do` could still be invalid node. I could certainly create a function to validade node, but I guess it would be out of the scope of the question, no? What's your suggestion?